# Splitting string using xml tags in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to `split` a `string` by replacing the spaces with `xml` tags in `sql`. I have a user defined function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[stringtoxml]
  (
   @string_to_split NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
   )
   RETURNS XML
   AS
   BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML
    SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@string_to_split, @delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'
    RETURN @xml
   END
```

I'm storing the `xml` in a field employee_name with a `datatype` of `xml`. In another table, I want to be able to read the first element as the first name, second element as the middle initial if the format is one alpha character followed by a full stop and the third element as the last name.

There are invalid characters in the `@string_to_split` - for example 'John O'Smith'.

Is there a way to get around the invalid characters without having to do:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string_to_split,'''','&apos;'),'&','&amp;'), @delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'
RETURN @xml
```

and then to do another replace to remove &apos and &amp when I'm reading the individual elements in the other table.

Comment: Is this `TSQL` for `SQL-Server`? Please tag the question appropriately. It makes a difference, as different database engines have different string/XML handling capabilities.

Comment: Hi, yes this is SQL-Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "XMLify" your string using `for xml path`.

Query:

```sql
declare @string_to_split nvarchar(max) = '&,<,>,'',"'
declare @delimiter nvarchar(100) = ','
declare @xml xml

set @xml = N'<t>' + replace((select @string_to_split for xml path('')), @delimiter, N'</t><t>') + N'</t>'

select @xml
```

Result:

```xml
<t>&amp;</t>
<t>&lt;</t>
<t>&gt;</t>
<t>'</t>
<t>"</t>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give it a go. How do I then un'XMLify' the xml elements so I can store element one as a string in employee_first column in another table?